# Parsing regex with alternatives and optionals

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, chatbot, rivescript

I'm building a chatbot subset of [RiveScript](https://www.rivescript.com/) and trying to build the pattern matching parser with regular expression. Which three regexes match the following three examples?

```
ex1: I am * years old
valid match:
- "I am 24 years old"
invalid match:
- "I am years old"

ex2: what color is [my|your|his|her] (bright red|blue|green|lemon chiffon) *
valid matches:
- "what color is lemon chiffon car"
- "what color is my some random text till the end of string"

ex3: [*] told me to say *
valid matches:
- "Bob and Alice told me to say hallelujah"
- "told me to say by nobody"
```

The wildcards mean any text that is not empty is acceptable.

In example 2, anything between `[ ]` is optional, anything between `( )` is alternative, each option or alternative is separated by a `|`.

In example 3, the `[*]` is an optional wildcard, meaning blank text can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. https://regex101.com/r/CuZuMi/4

   ```
   I am (?:\d+) years old
   ```
2. https://regex101.com/r/CuZuMi/2

   ```
   what color is.*(?:my|your|his|her).*(?:bright red|blue|green|lemon chiffon)?.*
   ```
3. https://regex101.com/r/CuZuMi/3

   ```
   .*told me to say.*
   ```

---

I am using mostly 2 things:

1. `(?:)` non-capture groups, to group things together like the parenthesis use on math.
2. `.*` match any character 0 or more times. Could be replaced by `{1,3}` to match between 1 and 3 times.

You can exchange `*` by `+` to match at least 1 character, instead of 0.
And the `?` after the non-capture group, makes that group optional.

---

These are golden place for you to start:

1. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html
2. https://regexone.com/
3. http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html
4. [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: What about this scenario `(.+ |.*)told me to say (.+)`. If there are characters before `told me to say `, there must also have a space in between ` ` to prevent word colliding, e.g. `Alice told me to say hi` and `told me to say hi` should work but `Alicetold me to say hi` doesn't.

Comment: Just remove the space as in `(.*)told me to say (.+)` and `Alicetold me to say hi` will match.