# Capturing optional groups in regex

Tags: regex

I need to capture the optional texts in a pattern, with the extracted examples `i`, `9`, `Caffè` and `you` in the following matched scenarios:

- Valid matches:

  ```
  love!
  9 love!
  love Caffè!
  i love you!
  ```
- Invalid matches:

  ```
  love
  iloveyou
  ```

My [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464120/parsing-regex-with-alternatives-and-optionals): `[*] love [*]!`, with `[*]` meaning blank text can be accepted to be captured.

I tried to make the regex `((?:.+) )?love( (?:.+))?!` ([online](https://regex101.com/r/aJWQHI/2)) but it failed to capture the correct texts.

Comment: What are the rules as to why you would match your valid examples, but not your invalid matches - There are quite a few ways to interpret this.

Comment: Well, maybe [`(?:(.+) )?love(?: (.+))?!`](https://regex101.com/r/aJWQHI/4) works as expected?

Comment: You say the texts are optional but then say "love" by itself is invalid. Well, which is it? Are you sure you understand your own requirements?

Comment: @CrayonViolent The "love" lacks the exclamation mark `!` after it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, thanks. I'm new to SO so I don't know how to close this question though.

Comment: @MiP Wiktor is meant to offer his solution as an answer so you can award it the green tick.  You can't give a green tick to a comment.  Wiktor has been here long enough to know that.

Comment: @MiP: I was not sure that was all there was to it. I posted an answer so that you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may swap your [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap):

```
(?:(.+) )?love(?: (.+))?!
 ^^            ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJWQHI/4)

Now, the text that you will have inside groups will be without spaces as they are part of the *non-capturing* groups that are only meant to group subpatterns.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but what if I want the character `!` optional, e.g.: https://regex101.com/r/ZptHNN/3 The current regex won't work correctly, like getting `you` from `i love you! not`.

Comment: Yes, the `!` is very important here since it is an obligatory subpattern and "anchors" the match on the right. What is the rule for the right hand boundary then?

Comment: Do you mean to make `(?: (.+))?` work correctly there should always be mandatory characters on the right instead of optionals?

Comment: Acc. to your comment, `love  or not` is a valid match, `(?:(.+) )?love(?: (.+))?(?: or)? not` matches it. Why should it be invalid?

Comment: `love<space>or<space>not` is a valid match, but `love<space><space>or<space>not` isn't.

Comment: Well, you may fail the match if there are two consecutive whitespace symbols after `love` - `(?:(.+) )?love(?: (\S.*))?(?: or)? not` or `(?:(.+) )?love(?!\s{2})(?: (.+))?(?: or)? not` will work then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136745/discussion-between-mip-and-wiktor-stribizew).